# Pre-image and set inclusion

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and $V$ be a subset of $Y$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ be a subset of $X$ say $U$. Now when we talk about $f(f^{-1}(V))$, do we say $f(U)\subset V$ or $f(U)=V$. Can there be an element in $V$ which is not in $f^{-1}(V)$ that is $U$?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2$ as a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, and let $V=[-1,1]$. Then $U=f^{-1}[V]=[0,1]$, and $f[U]=[0,1]\subsetneqq V$.

Comment: So $f(U)=V$ if and only if $f$ is onto $V$.

Comment: @RobertShore: $f$ being surjective *guarantees* that $f[U]=V$, but more generally what you need for a particular $V$ is $V\subseteq\operatorname{ran}f$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's the concept I was trying to communicate.  Thanks.